# How to prevent newline/line break within a <form></form>?

Tags: html, css, forms, newline, line-breaks

This is my code.

```
<form name="publish">
<?php include 'location.selector.html'; ?>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/> </form>
```

When displayed, there is a newline preceding the

> submit

button, how to eliminate this newline/line break?

The HTML content of location.selector.html is

```
<table><tr><td>都道府県を選択してください</td>
<td>市区町村を選択してください</td></tr>

<tr><td align="center">
<SELECT name="pref" onChange="changePref(true)">
<OPTION VALUE="99">全国
<OPTION VALUE="0">北海道
<OPTION VALUE="1">青森県
<OPTION VALUE="2">岩手県
<OPTION VALUE="3">宮城県
<OPTION VALUE="4">秋田県
<OPTION VALUE="5">山形県
<OPTION VALUE="6">福島県
<OPTION VALUE="7">茨城県
<OPTION VALUE="8">栃木県
<OPTION VALUE="9">群馬県
<OPTION VALUE="10">埼玉県
<OPTION VALUE="11">千葉県
<OPTION VALUE="12">東京都
<OPTION VALUE="13">神奈川県

<OPTION VALUE="14">新潟県
<OPTION VALUE="15">富山県
<OPTION VALUE="16">石川県
<OPTION VALUE="17">福井県
<OPTION VALUE="18">山梨県
<OPTION VALUE="19">長野県
<OPTION VALUE="20">岐阜県
<OPTION VALUE="21">静岡県
<OPTION VALUE="22">愛知県
<OPTION VALUE="23">三重県
<OPTION VALUE="24">滋賀県
<OPTION VALUE="25">京都府
<OPTION VALUE="26">大阪府
<OPTION VALUE="27">兵庫県
<OPTION VALUE="28">奈良県
<OPTION VALUE="29">和歌山県
<OPTION VALUE="30">鳥取県

<OPTION VALUE="31">島根県
<OPTION VALUE="32">岡山県
<OPTION VALUE="33">広島県
<OPTION VALUE="34">山口県
<OPTION VALUE="35">徳島県
<OPTION VALUE="36">香川県
<OPTION VALUE="37">愛媛県
<OPTION VALUE="38">高知県
<OPTION VALUE="39">福岡県
<OPTION VALUE="40">佐賀県
<OPTION VALUE="41">長崎県
<OPTION VALUE="42">熊本県
<OPTION VALUE="43">大分県
<OPTION VALUE="44">宮崎県
<OPTION VALUE="45">鹿児島県
<OPTION VALUE="46">沖縄県
</SELECT></td><td align="center">

<SELECT NAME="city">
<OPTION VALUE="99" SELECTED>全地区
<OPTION VALUE="">
<OPTION VALUE="">
<OPTION VALUE="">
<OPTION VALUE="">
<OPTION VALUE="">
<OPTION VALUE="">
<OPTION VALUE="">
</SELECT></td></tr></table>
```

Comment: look in the include file, it may be responsible.

Comment: You would most likely have to post the content of location.selector.html

Comment: I have posted the HTML content of location.selector.html.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Include the table before your form tag or use try using below CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
form, table {
     display:inline;
     margin:0px;
     padding:0px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 26):

It's been awhile since I did CSS but try the

```
display:inline
```

style.