# How to fix html form size?

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've got a table with few forms. The date is submit button:

[image]

And this is the same table without `form` tag(only `input type="submit"`):

[image]

As you can see, form tag adds new line. How can I avoid this?

The code:

```
<form id="command" action="/wifi/selection" method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" name="beginDate" value="2014-06-30">
   <input type="hidden" name="endDate" value="">
   <input type="hidden" name="apId" value="1824">
   <input type="hidden" name="ssidId"
      value="42">
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-link"
      value=" 2014-06-30" />
   <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="812810c6-9e41-434c-baec-b4db1680ce7a" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `style="display: inline;"` on the form might do it.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<style type="text/css'>
form {display:inline; margin:0px; padding:0px;}
</style>
```

This link will help: [How to prevent newline/line break within a <form></form>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858080/how-to-prevent-newline-line-break-within-a-form-form)